# How to keep a program with several executable keep running after ssh session closed?

Tags: linux, ssh, xterm, nohup, mobaxterm

I am working from home on VPN and my exceed or Mobaxterm window seems to close itself often. I am losing all the progress of my runs. The program calls for different executables while running also does restart the cycle in between checking results of those executables, basically it needs the window open. I tried nohup but it wasn't working for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
OS:
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

Comment: `screen` might be a good solution to this problem. It keeps a session on the server-side, which allows you to re-attach after a lost SSH connection. This blog provides some good information to get started: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Comment: Thanks . This seems to work.